# How does the width of a barrier in an open channel affect the flow velocity after it has gone past the barrier?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a question about open channel flow. If in an almost flat open channel with laminer flowing water, a barrier (such as a cuboid) how would that affect the flow? Are there any equations to describe this motion? Furthermore how does it affect the flow velocity afterwards? And what is the relationship between barrier width and velocity after barrier?

I've looked online but I cant seem to find any trace of formula(s) which describe this motion or an explanation as to what should be happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: are you familiar with the continuity equation for incompressible flow?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell (with my limited knowledge) is that unless the cross sectional area of the wetted area changes, the flowrate throughout the channel is constant. However I'm not sure how to apply to this scenario.

Comment: What do you envision the streamline pattern to look like in this situation?